# How to call the function with parameters when clicking on SVG circle element

Tags: javascript, svg

On a website, I need to use SVG map of a world and I want to change 5 dots to make them clickable and change their color and size. After a click, I want to show the popup with some description (using JS).

How to execute JS script when I will click on a particular dot. How to call the function and pass to it some parameters.

Below is part of a map in SVG.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" max-width="1000" max-height="820" viewBox="0 0 201 97"><g fill="rgba(0,0,72)"><circle cx="191" cy="90" r=".3"/><circle cx="190" cy="90" r=".3"/><circle cx="189" cy="90" r=".3"/><circle cx="192" cy="89" r=".3"/><circle cx="191" cy="89" r=".3"/><circle xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" cx="190" cy="89" r=".9" fill="rgba(204,153,24)"/><circle cx="193" cy="88" r=".3"/><circle cx="192" cy="88" r=".3"/><circle cx="178" cy="88" r=".3"/><circle cx="177" cy="88" r=".3"/><circle cx="194" cy="87" r=".3"/><circle cx="179" cy="87" r=".3"/><circle cx="178" cy="87" r=".3"/><circle cx="197" cy="86" r=".3"/><circle cx="196" cy="86" r=".3"/><circle cx="199" cy="85" r=".3"/><circle cx="198" cy="85" r=".3"/><circle cx="197" cy="85" r=".3"/><circle cx="179" cy="85" r=".3"/><circle cx="198" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="182" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="181" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="180" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="179" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="178" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="177" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="198" cy="83" r=".3"/><circle cx="182" cy="83" r=".3"/><circle cx="181" cy="83" r=".3"/><circle cx="180" cy="83" r=".3"/><circle cx="179" cy="83" r=".3"/><circle cx="178" cy="83" r=".3"/></g></svg>
```

I have tried a couple of solutions but nothing works so it makes no sense to paste it here.

Comment: this will help https://www.tutorialspoint.com/svg/svg_interactivity.htm#:~:text=We've%20used%20onClick%20event,on%20which%20event%20got%20raised.

Answer (score 2):

### Use querySelectorAll

First of all the circles are now more readable, and also the svg look better when the circle not very small :)

Second, I called them all by `document.querySelectorAll` and added to each `eventlistener` that would run a function by clicking.

and as you ask, change color and size, and an alert in comment if you want.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("circle")?.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
    const circle = ev.target;
    if (Number(circle.getAttribute("r")) === 2) {
      circle.style = "fill: green";
      circle.setAttribute("r", 4);
    } else {
      circle.style = "fill: rgba(0,0,72)";
      circle.setAttribute("r", 2);
    }
    // alert("some description (using JS)");
  })
})
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300" viewBox="-10 -10 100 100">
  <g fill="rgba(0,0,72)">
    <circle class="circle" cx="191" cy="90" r="2" />
    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="2" />
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="2" />
    <circle cx="5" cy="20" r="2" />
    <circle cx="10" cy="20" r="2" />
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="2" />
    <circle cx="30" cy="20" r="2" />
    <circle cx="40" cy="20" r="2" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="20" r="2" />
    <circle cx="60" cy="20" r="2" />
    <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="2" />
    <circle xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" cx="35" cy="10" r="3" fill="rgba(204,153,24)" />
    <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="2" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="2" />
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="2" />
    <circle cx="60" cy="5" r="2" />
    <circle cx="60" cy="10" r="2" />
    <circle cx="60" cy="20" r="2" />
    <circle cx="60" cy="30" r="2" />
    <circle cx="60" cy="40" r="2" />
    <circle cx="60" cy="50" r="2" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

SVG elements the DOM elements, so you can attach event handlers to them. That means you can either:

1. Attach a click handler to the specific dots you want to respond to, or
2. Attach a click handler to the map, and then check whether the click passed through the relevant dots (`circle` elements, it looks like) and do something if it did.

I wasn't sure which dots you meant, and clicking on them is tricky given how small they are, so here's an example of #2:

```js
document.getElementById("the-map").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    const circle = evt.target.closest("circle");
    if (circle && this.contains(circle)) {
        console.log("circle clicked");
    }
});
```

```html
<svg id="the-map" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" max-width="1000" max-height="820" viewBox="0 0 201 97"><g fill="rgba(0,0,72)"><circle cx="191" cy="90" r=".3"/><circle cx="190" cy="90" r=".3"/><circle cx="189" cy="90" r=".3"/><circle cx="192" cy="89" r=".3"/><circle cx="191" cy="89" r=".3"/><circle xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" cx="190" cy="89" r=".9" fill="rgba(204,153,24)"/><circle cx="193" cy="88" r=".3"/><circle cx="192" cy="88" r=".3"/><circle cx="178" cy="88" r=".3"/><circle cx="177" cy="88" r=".3"/><circle cx="194" cy="87" r=".3"/><circle cx="179" cy="87" r=".3"/><circle cx="178" cy="87" r=".3"/><circle cx="197" cy="86" r=".3"/><circle cx="196" cy="86" r=".3"/><circle cx="199" cy="85" r=".3"/><circle cx="198" cy="85" r=".3"/><circle cx="197" cy="85" r=".3"/><circle cx="179" cy="85" r=".3"/><circle cx="198" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="182" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="181" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="180" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="179" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="178" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="177" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="198" cy="83" r=".3"/><circle cx="182" cy="83" r=".3"/><circle cx="181" cy="83" r=".3"/><circle cx="180" cy="83" r=".3"/><circle cx="179" cy="83" r=".3"/><circle cx="178" cy="83" r=".3"/></g></svg>
```

I added an `id` to the map (but you can locate it in other ways instead). In response to a click, it checks whether the click passed through a `circle` and shows a console statement if it did.

To do a subset of circles, you might give them a class, like this:

```js
document.getElementById("the-map").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    const circle = evt.target.closest(".clickable");
    if (circle && this.contains(circle)) {
        console.log(".clickable clicked");
    }
});
```

```css
.clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg id="the-map" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" max-width="1000" max-height="820" viewBox="0 0 201 97"><g fill="rgba(0,0,72)"><circle cx="191" cy="90" r=".3"/><circle cx="190" cy="90" r=".3"/><circle cx="189" cy="90" r=".3"/><circle cx="192" cy="89" r=".3"/><circle cx="191" cy="89" r=".3"/><circle xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" cx="190" cy="89" r=".9" fill="rgba(204,153,24)" class="clickable"/><circle cx="193" cy="88" r=".3"/><circle cx="192" cy="88" r=".3"/><circle cx="178" cy="88" r=".3"/><circle cx="177" cy="88" r=".3"/><circle cx="194" cy="87" r=".3"/><circle cx="179" cy="87" r=".3"/><circle cx="178" cy="87" r=".3"/><circle cx="197" cy="86" r=".3"/><circle cx="196" cy="86" r=".3"/><circle cx="199" cy="85" r=".3"/><circle cx="198" cy="85" r=".3"/><circle cx="197" cy="85" r=".3"/><circle cx="179" cy="85" r=".3"/><circle cx="198" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="182" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="181" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="180" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="179" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="178" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="177" cy="84" r=".3"/><circle cx="198" cy="83" r=".3"/><circle cx="182" cy="83" r=".3"/><circle cx="181" cy="83" r=".3"/><circle cx="180" cy="83" r=".3"/><circle cx="179" cy="83" r=".3"/><circle cx="178" cy="83" r=".3"/></g></svg>
```

In that, only the orange-ish circle with `fill="rgba(204,153,24)"` (which I've added a class to) will respond to a click. To help you know when you're over it, I've added some CSS to change the pointer.